# Error in installing ActiveAdmin gem in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, activeadmin, has-scope

This is the error after I run bundle install in rails. I'm using rails 4. 
I already followed the instruction that given but nothings happen.

---

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name (https://rubygems.org/gems/has_scope-0.6.0.rc.gem)
An error occurred while installing has_scope (0.6.0.rc), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install has_scope -v '0.6.0.rc'` succeeds
before bundling.
```

---

### then, this is the gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem "meta_search"
gem 'bourbon', '3.2.1'
gem 'has_scope', '0.6.0.rc'
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: Did you do what the error told you?  `gem install has_scope -v '0.6.0.rc'`?  Works here.  RubyGems' server isn't always the greatest.

Comment: @NickVeys Yes, I already do the suggestion of the error but nothings happen. btw, this is the error after I type the gem install has_scope -v '0.6.0.rc'                                                 ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'has_scope' (= 0.6.0.rc), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/has_scope-0.6.0.rc.gemspec.rz)

Comment: The gem is valid and accessible. It seems your machine is having trouble resolving rubygems.org. Can you access the rubygems.org website in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a network problem. Try doing `traceroute rubygems.org` from your terminal and see if you are able to reach rubygems.org. If not try again sometime later or try a different host like http://ruby.taobao.org/. You can change the source in the Gemfile. It is usually the first line of the Gemfile, change from rubygems to the above link I gave you if `traceroute` does not work out.

Comment: It works using the http://ruby.taobao.org/.. Thank you so much. Also, for everyone who help me. Salamat(Thank you) :)